# I am Getting an InvalidStateError: ....... The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state. (Python3 Graphics Brython on CodeHS)

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphics, brython

For Context:
I am using "CodeHS Python3 Graphics(Brython)" on Chromium Version 121.0.6127.0 (Developer Build) (64-bit) Running on Windows11.

One of the images will display but the second one won't, I have already tried using different images.

I am getting the Following error when trying to execute my program:

```
InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state.
```

Here is My Code:

```
#Grass
def grass():
    rect = Rectangle(400,200)
    rect.set_color("green")
    rect.set_position(0,400)
    add(rect)
#Main Bulding
def left_tower_base():
    rect = Rectangle(100,200)
    rect.set_color("grey")
    rect.set_position(25,200)
    add(rect)
def right_tower_base():
    rect = Rectangle(100,200)
    rect.set_color("grey")
    rect.set_position(275,200)
    add(rect)
def middle_base():
    rect = Rectangle(200,145)
    rect.set_color("grey")
    rect.set_position(100,255)
    add(rect)
#Door
def door_rect():
    rect = Rectangle(100,80)
    rect.set_color("#6F4E37")
    rect.set_position(150,320)
    add(rect)
def door_circ():
    circ = Circle(50)
    circ.set_color("#6F4E37")
    circ.set_position(200,320)
    add(circ)
#Left Tower Roof
def left_roof_bottom():
    rect = Rectangle(140,25)
    rect.set_color("#483C32")
    rect.set_position(5,180)
    add(rect)
def left_roof_2():
    rect = Rectangle(120,25)
    rect.set_color("#483C32")
    rect.set_position(15,160)
    add(rect)
def left_roof_3():
    rect = Rectangle(100,25)
    rect.set_color("#483C32")
    rect.set_position(25,140)
    add(rect)
def left_roof_4():
    rect = Rectangle(80,25)
    rect.set_color("#483C32")
    rect.set_position(35,120)
    add(rect)
def left_roof_5():
    rect = Rectangle(60,25)
    rect.set_color("#483C32")
    rect.set_position(45,100)
    add(rect)
def left_roof_6():
    rect = Rectangle(40,15)
    rect.set_color("#483C32")
    rect.set_position(55,85)
    add(rect)
#Right Tower Roof
def right_roof_bottom():
    rect = Rectangle(140,25)
    rect.set_color("#483C32")
    rect.set_position(255,180)
    add(rect)
def right_roof_2():
    rect = Rectangle(120,25)
    rect.set_color("#483C32")
    rect.set_position(265,160)
    add(rect)
def right_roof_3():
    rect = Rectangle(100,25)
    rect.set_color("#483C32")
    rect.set_position(275,140)
    add(rect)
def right_roof_4():
    rect = Rectangle(80,25)
    rect.set_color("#483C32")
    rect.set_position(285,120)
    add(rect)
def right_roof_5():
    rect = Rectangle(60,25)
    rect.set_color("#483C32")
    rect.set_position(295,100)
    add(rect)
def right_roof_6():
    rect = Rectangle(40,15)
    rect.set_color("#483C32")
    rect.set_position(305,85)
    add(rect)
#Left Window
def left_window_rect():
    rect = Rectangle(50,30)
    rect.set_color("black")
    rect.set_position(50,240)
    add(rect)
def left_window_circ():
    circ = Circle(25)
    circ.set_color("black")
    circ.set_position(75,237)
    add(circ)
#Right Window
def right_window_rect():
    rect = Rectangle(50,30)
    rect.set_color("black")
    rect.set_position(300,240)
    add(rect)

def right_window_circ():
    circ = Circle(25)
    circ.set_color("black")
    circ.set_position(325,237)
    add(circ)

#Lightning
def lightning():
    bolts = Image("https://static.vecteezy.com/" +
                            "system/resources/previews/021/883/120/original/" +
                            "lightning-bolt-thunderbolt-flat-and-doodle-style-png.png")
    bolts.set_size(110.5, 120)
    bolts.set_position(100,10)
    add(bolts)

def clouds():
    cloud = Image("https://www.clipartmax.com/" +
                            "png/small/" +
                            "0-2605_clipart-info-cloud-with-lightning-clipart.png")
    cloud.set_size(269, 275)
    cloud.set_position(100,100)
    add(cloud)

#Makes The Castle
grass()
left_tower_base()
middle_base()
right_tower_base()
door_rect()
door_circ()
left_roof_bottom()
left_roof_2()
left_roof_3()
left_roof_4()
left_roof_5()
left_roof_6()
right_roof_bottom()
right_roof_2()
right_roof_3()
right_roof_4()
right_roof_5()
right_roof_6()
left_window_rect()
left_window_circ()
right_window_rect()
right_window_circ()
lightning()
clouds()
```

Here is the Result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPci4.png)